# URL Query string is not querying JSON response

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Building a typeahead in angular 5 app. Using the Heros Search from angular docs as an example.

As soon a character is entered in the input field, it returns all items but further typing does not filter the list.

template:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Additive Type..." />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
  </span>
</div>
<ul class="search-result">
  <li *ngFor="let activity of activities$ | async">{{activity.ActivityName}}</li>
</ul>
```

component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ActivityService } from '../../services/car.service';
import { ActivityType } from '../../interfaces/ActivityType';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activity-search',
  templateUrl: './activity-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activity-search.component.css']
})
export class ActivitySearchComponent implements OnInit {
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  activities$: Observable<ActivityType[]>;

  constructor(private _activitiyService: ActivityService) { }

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activities$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300)
      , distinctUntilChanged()
      , switchMap((term: string) => this._activitiyService.searchActivities(term))
    );
  }
}
```

Service http get:

```
searchActivities(term: string): Observable<ActivityType[]> {
if (!term.trim()) {
  return of([]);  //return empty array if no match
}
  return this.http.get<ActivityType[]>(this.activityUrl + term, { withCredentials: true }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Returned json string from service looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "ActivityTypeId": 61,
    "ActivityName": "Driving"
  },
  {
    "ActivityTypeId": 62,
    "ActivityName": "Hiking"
  },
```

I am trying to filter on the ActivityName but if I type into the input field "dri" I still get driving and hiking, etc.

I checked chrome dev tools and it is sending a new get with each key press and it is passing the search term.  Looks like:

```
http://localhost:53162/api/activity/?ActivityName=dri
```

I also tried it without the last slash, but no difference:

```
http://localhost:53162/api/activity?ActivityName=dri
```

Comment: Could be you are running a function named `searchAdditive` on `keyup`, but there is no function with that name in the component? Or is the code above not the correct code?

Comment: @R.Richards - sorry, no that is the search function, I just copied over the wrong name.  It is definitely doing the search and returning stuff, it just returns everything instead of filtering on the search term.

Comment: If you're expecting the backend to do the filtering, then we need to see the backend code

Comment: It seems like the filtering is happening at the backend (at the API you are calling). Could something be wrong there?

Comment: @R.Richards - This may be where I have gone completely wrong.  No the api does no filtering.  All it does is return the full list and I am assuming the '?' in the url is supposed to then filter the returned list of objects based on the 'ActivityName' term passed int he url.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the query parameters are just a way of passing information in the URL. The front end doesn't do anything with it. If you want to filter the data, you'll either need to do so in your Angular code (maybe using the array.filter function), or in the backend

Comment: That is incorrect. You have to do more than that to filter the results. You are getting an array of values from the API, try using some [array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to narrow down the results based on the term.